# I want to be assured that pandera doesn't fiddle with the data i have in my data base which is sensitive and confidential

Tags: validation, pandera

I want to use pandera for data validation and i also want to make sure that the data sanctity is maintained which is why i'm reluctant to use it right away.

I expect it to not store my data anywhere for security purposes.